# Refactoring duplicate code that differs by type

Tags: c#, oop, generics, inheritance, refactoring

I built some test helper methods that build a mock DBContext for entity framework. These methods contain duplicate code and I'm assuming there has to be a better way to do this. I just can't figure out how. I tried creating a MockDbContextBuilder<> class, but that failed because I couldn't have a DbSet<>. Any ideas? Here are three examples of the methods I'm trying to refactor into one:

```
    private Mock<IPSNContext> BuildMockDbContext(List<TestEntity> list)
    {
        _mockDbSet = new Mock<DbSet<TestEntity>>();
        _mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<TestEntity>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(list.AsQueryable().Provider);
        _mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<TestEntity>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(list.AsQueryable().Expression);
        _mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<TestEntity>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(list.AsQueryable().ElementType);
        _mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<TestEntity>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(list.AsQueryable().GetEnumerator());

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            _mockDbSet.Setup(m => m.Find(item.Id)).Returns(item);
        }

        var mockContext = new Mock<IPSNContext>();
        mockContext.Setup(c => c.Set<TestEntity>())
                    .Returns(_mockDbSet.Object);
        return mockContext;
    }

    private Mock<IPSNContext> BuildMockDbContext(List<MessageBoardTopic> list)
    {
        _mockDbSet = new Mock<DbSet<MessageBoardTopic>>();
        _mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<MessageBoardTopic>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(list.AsQueryable().Provider);
        _mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<MessageBoardTopic>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(list.AsQueryable().Expression);
        _mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<MessageBoardTopic>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(list.AsQueryable().ElementType);
        _mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<MessageBoardTopic>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(list.AsQueryable().GetEnumerator());

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            _mockDbSet.Setup(m => m.Find(item.Id)).Returns(item);
        }

        var mockContext = new Mock<IPSNContext>();
        mockContext.Setup(c => c.Set<MessageBoardTopic>())
                    .Returns(_mockDbSet.Object);        
        return mockContext;
    }

    private Mock<IPSNContext> BuildMockDbContext(List<MessageBoardReply> list)
    {
        _mockDbSet = new Mock<DbSet<MessageBoardReply>>();
        _mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<MessageBoardReply>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(list.AsQueryable().Provider);
        _mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<MessageBoardReply>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(list.AsQueryable().Expression);
        _mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<MessageBoardReply>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(list.AsQueryable().ElementType);
        _mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<MessageBoardReply>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(list.AsQueryable().GetEnumerator());

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            _mockDbSet.Setup(m => m.Find(item.Id)).Returns(item);
        }

        var mockContext = new Mock<IPSNContext>();
        mockContext.Setup(c => c.Set<MessageBoardReply>())
                    .Returns(_mockDbSet.Object);
        return mockContext;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a method with an generic type, like that:

```
    private Mock<IPSNContext> BuildMockDbContext<T>(List<T> list)
    {
                _mockDbSet = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();
                _mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(list.AsQueryable().Provider);
                _mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(list.AsQueryable().Expression);
                _mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(list.AsQueryable().ElementType);
                _mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(list.AsQueryable().GetEnumerator());

                foreach (var item in list)            
                    _mockDbSet.Setup(m => m.Find(item.Id)).Returns(item);            

                var mockContext = new Mock<IPSNContext>();
                mockContext.Setup(c => c.Set<MessageBoardTopic>())
                            .Returns(_mockDbSet.Object);

                return mockContext;
   }
```

Comment: this worked. Thanks. Because DbSet<T> expects T to be a class, I just needed to add 
private Mock<IPSNContext> BuildMockDbContext<T>(List<T> list) **where TEntity : class, new()**